# Busybox sed does not work as expected with HEX - Android

Tags: android, sed, busybox

```
dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p11 of=/sdcard/mmcblk0p11
cat /sdcard/mmcblk0p11 | sed 's/This build is for\x00development purposes only\x00Do not distribute outside of HTC\x00without HTC\x27s written permission.\x00Failure to comply may\x00lead to legal action./                 \x00                         \x00                                \x00                                 \x00                     \x00                     /g' > /sdcard/mmcblk0p11new
```

I am trying to edit the hboot using a sed command. When I run the command on my Linux it works perfectly. It creates another file with the HTC message removed. When I run it in recovery or in an adb shell it does not work. It creates a new file but with no changes. What is the correct synatx on android?

Is there a way to make Linux's sed binary to work on Android? I am using Kali Linux

Comment: do you try with a double quoted version of the sed action list ?

Comment: yep I tried that. The same output

Comment: (no need of a cat before a sed, just give the name of the file at the last argument of the sed call). sur of your `\x00` in your file. By default sed work line by line, if this is interpreted by a line breaker (NL, CR or both), this sed will never find a match.

Comment: yes but the file I am trying to change is a binary file. There are no new lines so I assume it will search for the end of file. It works perfectly on my linux machine. (I've removed cat and put the input file at the end..It still works perfectly on the linux but not on android)

Comment: sed on a binary file could give unexpected result. Try maybe to first load the whole file via a `1h;1!H;${x;#YourCodeHere;}` but I suspect you loose special char (in a text point of view) taht could be unwanted in binary file